# Use a checkbox to toggle class of closest input

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a form with a series of input fields - each of which has an 'Unavailable' option. I'm trying to set it so that a CSS class (disabled) can be applied to the input that the checkboxes are closest to, rather than trying to write events for each pair of checkboxes/inputs.

Alternatively i could apply the attribute readonly to the input itself, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

my current attempt:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
Input: <input  type="text" name="something" id="_1" />
unavailable? <input type ="checkbox" class="unavailable" name="check" />    
</div>
<div>
Input: <input type="text" name="something" id="_2" />
unavailable? <input type ="checkbox" class="unavailable" name="check" />    
</div>
<div>
Input: <input type="text" name="something" id="_3" />
unavailable? <input type ="checkbox" class="unavailable" name="check" />    
</div>
```

Jquery

```
  $('.unavailable').change(function() {
    $(this).closest(input).toggleClass("disabled");
});
```

[Jsfiddle of attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/g5u0grLm/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
$('.unavailable').change(function() {
   $(this).prev("input[type=text]").toggleClass("disabled");
});
```

I also changed `display:none` to `visibility:hidden`, so the checkbox would shift with the text input is hidden.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksq205Lo/)

For the sake of a friendly interface however, I would toggle the disabled attribute of the input. That way the input will disabled, but just greyed-out, not removed completely. This will be a more familiar interface feature than altogether hiding the box.

```
$('.unavailable').change(function() {
    var i = $(this).prev("input[type=text]"),
        d = i.attr("disabled");
        i.attr("disabled", !d);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sypz3zea/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$(this).closest('div').find('input').toggleClass("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```
$('.unavailable').change(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]').toggleClass("disabled");
});
```